# How can one find a polynomial with a given solution?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

I was just looking at "algebraic" or non-transcendental numbers and apparently every number that can be created with multiplication, addition, subtraction, reciprocation, and radicals using a finite number of terms is algebraic and the solution to a polynomial with integer coefficients. Given a certain algebraic number, how can one find the corresponding polynomial with integer coefficients? Is it easier or harder than solving for the solutions of a degree 5+ polynomial?

Comment: "*Given a certain algebraic number*" $\;-\;$ How are you being "*given*" that number? Most algebraic numbers cannot be represented in terms of radicals or elementary functions.

Comment: Really? Can you give an example of a polynomial whose solutions can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions?

Comment: Classical example is the real root of $x^5-x-1$. Lookup the [Abel-Ruffini theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%E2%80%93Ruffini_theorem).

Comment: Jeez so there are non-trancendental numbers that are impossible to represent with radicals? That's rough. Does it go the other way? Could one conceive of an expression in terms of elementary functions and radicals such that no finite polynomial would have it as a solution?

Comment: Sums, products and roots of algebraic numbers are algebraic numbers themselves, so any expression that starts from rational numbers and uses only those operations results in an algebraic number. It may be tedious to determine the corresponding polynomial, but it is always possible. The technique in the posted [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4306509/291201) covers the simpler cases, though expressions like for example $\,1+\sqrt[3]{2}+\sqrt[3]{4}\,$ require more work.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, you'd do something like this:

Let's say we wanted to find a polynomial that has $x=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt[7]{87}}}{4}$ as a root. We do the following:

\begin{align*}
x&=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt[7]{87}}}{4}\\
4x&=\sqrt{1+\sqrt[7]{87}}\\
16x^2&=1+\sqrt[7]{87}\\
16x^2-1&=\sqrt[7]{87}\\
(16x^2-1)^7&=87\\
(16x^2-1)^7-87&=0\\
\end{align*}

So $f(x)=(16x^2-1)^7-87$ has $x=\frac{\sqrt{1+\sqrt[7]{87}}}{4}$ as a root.

Comment: That seems like a nice and prudent way to go about it. Thanks.